Running windows container's command prompt and a command
I am running Windows Nanoserver in a container.The nanoserver contains only the command prompt and nodejs that I have installed at the build time and it lacks powershell.
I want to execute certain commands inside the container in the command prompt
docker exec <container_id> cmd
But, is there any other way using which we can run docker exec <container_id> cmd together with another command what its executed inside the container?

psenter, psexec it is still windows and depending on if you installed the ssh it's also available
